# Sphinx Issue with Ruby 1.9.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sphinx, thinking-sphinx, ruby-1.9.3

I have recently moved a web app from ruby 1.8.7 to 1.9.3 and everything is going great, except for searching. Everything was working fine before bumping ruby. Here's my controller code:

```
ids = Business.simple_search_for_ids_with_location(@term, @city, @state, {}, :per_page => 2500)
      @results = Business.paginate :conditions => { :id => ids }, :page => ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize(params[:page]), :include => [:category]
      @results = @results.sort{|a,b| a.name.downcase <=> b.name.downcase}
      @count = @results.total_entries
```

And from my model:

```
def self.simple_search_for_ids_with_location(term, city, state, conditions={}, options={})
  ids = Business.compact_search_for_ids(term, {:conditions => { :address_city => city, :address_state => state }.merge(conditions), :order => :business_name}.merge(options))
  if state.blank?
    by_state = Business.compact_search_for_ids(term, {:conditions => { :address_state => city }.merge(conditions), :order => :business_name}.merge(options))
    ids += by_state
  end
  ids
end

def self.compact_search_for_ids(*args)
  search_for_ids(*args).compact
end
```

When running in the browser I get `undefined method total_entries for []:Array`

And the offending line is `@count = @results.total_entries`

I have made sure that sphinx is installed and thinking_sphinx has indexed and is running.

It appears that everything is working somewhat, but an empty array is being returned? Why would this have worked fine before?

I appreciate any help I can get here, as I really don't want to go back to ruby 1.8.7. Thank you.

Comment: change total_entries to count or length...

Comment: I've done that, and that's fine it does resolve the 'error'. However, I am wondering why my results are not coming through. If I run `>> ids = Business.simple_search_for_ids_with_location('surf', 'atlantic beach', 'fl', {}, :per_page => 2500)` in the console I get an empty array. I know for a fact that there are businesses in that fit that search criteria.

Comment: Which version of Thinking Sphinx are you using, and which version were you using on 1.8.7? Also, can you share the Sphinx index definition for your Business model?

Comment: Using 1.4.11 now was using 1.4 with ruby 1.8.7 here's the index: https://gist.github.com/shorepound/c7eefb49a75761324406e0e574b81b47

Comment: I updated riddle from 1.3.3 to 1.5 and now I'm getting an error: `ThinkingSphinx::SphinxError: index business_core: sort-by attribute 'business_name_sort' not found`

Comment: With the updated riddle, can you run `rake ts:rebuild` and then see if that helps with the search?

Comment: `rake ts:rebuild` aborted execution expired. @pat I thank you for helping me.

Comment: Here's the trace https://gist.github.com/shorepound/c66b1a14a6c56a87053f8adad5c97434 again @pat I am very grateful for your help.

Comment: I killed the pid for the searchd and successfully ran ts:rebuild, unfortunately, same error.

Comment: Sometimes you need to delete the application's /db/sphinx directory prior to running the rebuild (I don't think you're supposed to have to, but it's worked for me in the past).

Comment: No luck, but thank you @BradWerth

Comment: It seems from that gist you're using a very recent version of Sphinx. I'm not sure if the TS/Riddle versions you're using will support that - you may need to downgrade (I'd start with a 2.0.x release of Sphinx to see if that helps?). Also, can you share the output of a working rebuild run? And finally: is the consistent error now the business_name_sort not found one?

Comment: Oh, and given this thread of comments is getting rather long - you're welcome to open up an issue in the TS repo if that's easier: https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx

Comment: @pat here's the rebuild output: https://gist.github.com/shorepound/3d1d3289f9c1bb2ecfd5f9b32d8b35a8 And yes the error is: `ThinkingSphinx::SphinxError (index business_core: sort-by attribute 'business_name_sort' not found)`

Comment: Hey @pat, I did brew uninstall sphinx, downloaded 2.0.6 and installed, everything is now working. Thanks again, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was found through some discussion in the comments above. A couple of thoughts that may help others who come across similar issues:

- If you're using Thinking Sphinx v1.x or 2.x, best to stick to old Sphinx versions. No higher than Sphinx v2.0.x is recommended.
- Make sure you run `rake ts:rebuild` when upgrading Thinking Sphinx, and certainly when upgrading Sphinx itself (its indices format often changes between minor releases).
- If you're able to upgrade to more recent versions of Ruby/Rails/Thinking Sphinx, that's always going to help for long-term maintenance (but understandably not always possible).